# ASP.NET Authentication and IE11 internal server error 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-membership, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue with one of our web applications, the application uses the Membership framework and users are failing to login with IE11.

When users try to post back the login page IIS throws an internal server error 500 and doesn't show a .NET error (only happens in IE11)

at this point these are the things i have observed.

1. Fails only on IE11 (works on other IE versions and chrome, firefox)
2. IE11 seems to be redirecting the url to a cookie-less url like

https://www.example.com/(F(_QRiE7bzmjONkmbTY4ak8E_kE_hi_Jft4S9iVO4qsL6G4noS4-o5Ry6wjvE3VblzcOAHcHy4C_9Zy2XPfASI1KtPo7f_jHpJWFnjyZqySKX8CsYdQC198Gzw3bVYng6ChGSx0Lq8SViCyN8F2H0c2MwjB4-uet0AeHIDjOo0wsWOv3sgf2s28cqdnqq6Eqks2BVP-Q2))/route?aspxerrorpath=/route

1. We are running iis 7.0 on Windows 2008 DataCenter Edition
2. Application pool is running on .NET version 4.0

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: how did you implement membership and which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: MVC3, not sure what you mean by "how did you implement membership", its just the standard Membership Framework that Microsoft has released for so long.

Comment: what steps you followed to implement membership in your application

Comment: @MillerKoijam There is nothing wrong with the implementation of the membership framework, this has been in production for years, it has something to do with IE11 and IIS as i suspect so your question is irrelevant.

Comment: FYI, We have 7 sites running on asp.net mvc 3 with asp.net membership and working fine in ie11 and iis 7 in windows 2008. we are not facing any such issues.

Comment: I made a silly assumption its not IIS 7.5 it's 7.0 my other servers are on 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was rectified by setting the cookieless="UseCookies" attribute on the authentication section of the web.config

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" path="/" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="15" cookieless="UseCookies" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </authentication>
```

The specific issue is due to IIS 7.0 not recognizing IE11 and sending a cookie less response to the browser resulting in the Url mentioned in the question,

Microsoft should rectify this in IIS 7.0 in an update.

Further information available in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3e9f3c92-8724-4f41-9be3-34c2877ada0f/ie11-session-id-in-url) discussion